Getting object member at compile time
I'd like to make a compile-time map in which I'll connect a number to a member of a class. Then return member of a class from a function at compile-time.
This is the current code
class MyClass
{
public:
    float MemberA;
    std::uint32_t MemberB;
};

int ProcessMember(int iMemberID, MyClass* pClass)
{
    if (iMemberID == 1){
        ProcessMember(pClass->MemberA);
    }
    else if (iMemberID == 2){
        ProcessMember(pClass->MemberB);
    }
    endif
}

This is what I'd like to do:
template <class T>     
void Multiply(T& CurrentValue)     
{
    CurrentValue = CurrentValue * 2;
}

int ProcessMember(int iMemberID, MyClass* pClass)
{
   if (iMemberID == 1){
      Multiply(func(1));
    }
   else if (iMemberID == 2){
      Multiply(func(2));
    }
   endif
}

So the function will take a compile-time argument and will point to the member of MyClass that I want it to.
Is this possible?
I tried this:
template <typename T>         
T& GetValueFromValueName(int MemberID, MyClass* pClass)         
{            
    switch (MemberID) 
    {             
        case 1:                 
            return pClass>MemberA;             
        case 2:                 
            return pClass->MemberB;         
    }
}

But this only compiles if I specify T in advance before calling the function.

You are aware of that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file?r=Saves_AllUserSaves ?

you could do something like if constexpr (MemberId == 1) { return pClass->MemberA; } and make sure you have a return type of type auto& (unless you're really sure all your members have the same type).

@PepijnKramer Please do not answer in comments.

The return type of a function cannot be determined at runtime but it must be known at compile time.
You can make memberID a template argument, then either use specializations:
template <int memberID>
auto& GetValueFromValueName(MyClass* pClass);

template <>
auto& GetValueFromValueName<1>(MyClass* pClass) { return pClass->MemberA; }
template <>
auto& GetValueFromValueName<2>(MyClass* pClass) { return pClass->MemberB; }

Or constexpr if:
template <int memberID>
auto& GetValueFromValueName(MyClass* pClass) { 
    if constexpr (memberID == 1) return pClass->MemberA;
    else return pClass->MemberB;
}



This is what I'd like to do: [...]

I suppose what you actually want is to not spell out each case individually, because if you do that there is no benefit of writing test(1) instead of pClass->MemberA. With the above you can write:
template <int memberID>
auto ProcessMember(MyClass* pClass)
{
    return Multiply(GetValueFromValueName<memberID>(pClass));
}


Using the boost::pfr library, you can access member variables by compile-time constants.
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "boost/pfr.hpp"

class MyClass {
public:
    float MemberA;
    std::uint32_t MemberB;
};

template <class T>     
void Multiply(T& CurrentValue) {
    CurrentValue = CurrentValue * 2;
}

template<std::size_t i>
void ProcessMember(MyClass* pClass) {
    Multiply(boost::pfr::get<i>(*pClass));
}

int main() {
    MyClass c{ 3.14f, 12345 };
    std::cout << boost::pfr::io(c) << std::endl;

    ProcessMember<0>(&c);
    ProcessMember<1>(&c);
    std::cout << boost::pfr::io(c) << std::endl;
}

Result:
{3.14, 12345}
{6.28, 24690}

Demo
